# Oracle-Patch4 error instaltion

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

When I try to install Oracle patch 4 I face the below error

[image]

Comment: Is that really Forms 6i Patch 4? A piece of software that is almost seventeen years old? Surely not. More details please about what you are doing (and why).

Comment: yes it Forms 6i Patch 4 I try to install this instead of patch 2,

Comment: Why *just* Patch 4? Why not the most recent 6i patch (which is, I think, 19; http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/6i-forms-084462.html)?

Comment: I think its related to the parameter in the registry, but I don't know the what should be edited

Comment: Value name: FORMS60_PATH
Value data:
I:\PAYROLL\FORMS;I:\ASSETS\FORMS;I:\Security\FORMS;I:\;I:\Stat\FORMS